# caught segfault memory not mapped R

Tags: r, segmentation-fault

I am working on a data frame (30 rows x 54676 columns), and am trying to perform a glm expression on it. I started up R and ran the code below, and keep ending up with

*** caught segfault *** address ... 'memory not mapped'

I read it may be a package bug, but am not which package I would need to uninstall. Is it possibly a version issue?

The following is the information I got from R while bringing up the error

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
a=read.table('GDS4521.soft',skip=77,sep='\t',nrows=54675,header=1,row.names=1)
> 
> a=a[,-1]
> 
> for (i in 1:ncol(a)){
+ a[,i]=a[,i]/a['200650_s_at',i]
+ }
> 
> a=data.frame(t(a))
> a=cbind(a,hadStroke=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20)))
> a$hadStroke=factor(a$hadStroke) 
> set.seed(2134)
> s=sample(40,30)
> training=a[s,]
> dim(training)
[1]    30 54676
> mod=glm(hadStroke~.,data=training,family=binomial)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f0603061fbc, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: terms.formula(formula, data = data)
 2: terms(formula, data = data)
 3: model.frame.default(formula = hadStroke ~ ., data = training,         drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
 4: stats::model.frame(formula = hadStroke ~ ., data = training,     vdrop.unused.levels = TRUE)
 5: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
 6: eval(mf, parent.frame())
 7: glm(hadStroke ~ ., data = training, family = binomial)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: Segfaults are always bugs. You should update to the latest R release to see if that fixes the issue. If not, you should report this as a bug.

Comment: In order to report this as a bug, though, it really needs to be *reproducible*.  Can you post your data or simulate a data set with similar structure that gives the same result?

Comment: the data is from (www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser?acc=GDS4521), and I downloaded the Dataset SOFT file

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I just ran the same code on a windows OS and it came out with 'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.1 Gb', so I guess it is maybe a memory issue, and I should trim my data frame?